# Connect to VMware workstation vitural machine from another computer on the network

Tags: networking, web-server, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

How can I set up the networking on my VMware Workstation so that I may connect to webpages hosted on the VM within the same network? Update: Tried bridge networking and can not get it to connect to the internet when turned on.

Comment: Two things to consider: bridged networking and port forwarding.

Comment: Which one is easier to accomplish? Since it isnt my own router I would then think bridged networking. @EEAA

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with your router. Also, it has nothing to do with professional systems administration.

Comment: @EEAA ok, I was only used to port forwarding on a router. What are some good resources to set up a port foward/bridged connection?

Comment: How about the VMware Workstation manual for start?

Comment: @EEAA I tried to look at it. I am not really a networking person so get lost at some parts of it.

Comment: @EEAA selected bridged network like it said and didn't work any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your guest OS is configured to use NAT, you should forward your host's port 80 to your guest's port 80. That's if you want to access webpages on your guest OS using the normal http port.

If your guest OS is configured to use bridged then  it should automatically be available on your network as long as it managed to acquire IP from your router/DHCP server and port 80 is open on your guest OS.

Comment: How do I acquire the IP from the router? I am trying bridged and it won't connect to the network.

Comment: First, you have to configure your guest OS to use DHCP. It's the same as obtaining IP address automatically on Windows machines. I don't know what OS your guest is using so I can't provide exact procedure how to enable DCHP on your guest.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help!